# Creating graphic from a window at full size

Tags: c#, winforms, image, printing

I have a window which I can resize. I want to print a full snapshot of this window, regardless of the size of the window. For example:

Window is normally 800 x 600 but can be as small as 300 x 300 but I still want to print at 800 x 600 pixels.

When I use `Graphics mygraphics = this.CreateGraphics()` I get a small image not at the desired size.

Comment: What kind of drawing is being done on this window?  Is it just controls?  Do you have a custom drawing routine?  It's generally bad practice to draw a control directly to a page.  You just want to draw the content, not the buttons/etc.  What type of content do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to hold the "graphic" in a background bitmap:

```
Bitmap myImage = new Bitmap(800, 600);
```

And to draw on it:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myImage)) {
  // do stuff:
}
```